# Automating GNUStep from Notepad++

Tags: objective-c, makefile, mingw, notepad++, gnustep

I use GNUStep to compile Objective-C on Windows 7 using GCC and MinGW. I'd like to be able to automate the "make" instruction (with make files) from Notepad++ and have any complier errors reported to Notepad++s console window.

Edit:
What I am trying to do is script GNUStep/Bash to login to the right directory, build the directory, then exit. Currently I have to type in the following:

```
sh -login -i
$ cd d:\directory
$ make
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it, with considerable help from my friends.

1. Create a Bash script called 'nppmake'. I saved it in c:\GNUStep. The file should contain the following:

   #! /bin/bash

   cd $1
   make
2. Create a DOS batch file called 'nppmake.bat', which again I saved in c:\GNUStep. This file contains the following:

   sh --login -i C:\GNUstep\nppmake %1
3. In N++, go to 'Plugins > NppExec > Execute' and type in the following:

   C:\GNUstep\nppmake.bat $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
4. Hit 'Save' and call the script 'make'.
5. In 'Plugins > NppExec > Advanced Options...', create a menu item, which I called 'Build' and associate it to the script called 'make' (I'm a Visual Studio developer, so 'build' feels more natural to me). Make sure 'Place to the Macros submenu' is checked.
6. You may need to restart N++ at this point, but then all that is left to do is add the keyboard shortcut. Go to 'Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands' and find 'Build'. I assigned 'Ctrl-Shift-B', is it is the same as VS.

You're done. Now open up a file in a Objective-C project, that has a GNUmakefile, and hit 'Ctrl-Shift-B'. The NppExec window reports any errors, or hopefully a successful build!

Answer (score 2):

The [npp-plugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/) gives you most of what you are looking for. Install the plugin and:

- Press F6 to open the NppExec Execute window
- Type 'make' (you may also want to cd to the proper directory first) and click OK
- Output from make is shown in the notepad++ console

Another cool feature is that it will save the command if you restart notepad++, so you only  need to type 'make' a single time.

You may need to make some tweaks to only show compiler errors, however.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not NppExec I'm having problems with, it's scripting Bash. I can start an interactive shell by typing in "sh -login -i" into NppExec, but I have to manually change directory and type in make each time. I would like to hit a button and have N++ login to bash and build the working folder, then either exit or report errors. I wish I hadn't wound up my Linux friends quite so much now.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small correction to kim3er's answer.

`cd $1 make`

should be

```
cd $1 
make
```