# Compiling Objective C with GNUStep from Notepad++

Tags: objective-c, batch-file, compiler-errors, notepad++, sh

I am trying to setup GNUStep to compile Objective-C code with Notepad++ in
Windows 10.

i came across one solution on stackoverflow provided by the user kim3er.(link below)

[Automating GNUStep from Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442819/automating-gnustep-from-notepad)

when i implement this solution it get this error

```
 NPP_EXEC: "make"
C:\GNUstep\nppmake.bat C:\Users\Michael\Desktop
Process started >>>

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++>sh --login -i C:\GNUstep\nppmake C:\Users\Michael\Desktop 
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

has anyone came across this error and found a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question you pointed to mentioned they have MinGW installed.  You can add MSYS to get some more tools (like bash)

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys

Or get those from Cygwin.

If you think you have `sh`, make sure it's in your PATH.